# Remove html section tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML page that has a couple of `section` tags, but I would only like to remove the section that starts with:

```
<section class="news-rsf-abstract"></section>
```

Here is the whole HTML page:

```
<div id="chunk_content">
<div class="newsHeadingData">
<div class="row">
Oct 28 2015 07:59:12
</div>
</div>



<newsstory>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="application/xhtml+xml" property="Content-Type">
    <title>News Story</title>

  <section class="news-rsf-abstract"><ul>
<li>Drugstore deal valued at $17.2 billion including debt</li>
<li>Walgreens adjusted earnings of 88 cents top 81-cent estimate</li>
</ul></section><section class="news-header"><p class="news-byline" itemprop="Byline"><meta content="http://bloomberg.com/StoryFormat/NewsIndividualAttribution" itemprop="BylineType">By <span itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><link href="http://bloomberg.com/StoryFormat/ContactInfo" itemprop="additionalType">
<span itemprop="workLocation" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place"><meta content="New York" itemprop="name"></span><meta content="4538381" itemprop="uuid">
<meta content="2491003" itemprop="pepl">
<meta content="by" itemprop="role">
<meta content="reporter" itemprop="role">
<meta content="Crayton Harrison" itemprop="name">Crayton Harrison</span></p>
<span class="news-dateline" itemprop="NewsDateline" itemscope="itemscope"><meta content="New York" itemprop="location">
<meta content="Bloomberg" itemprop="publisher">(Bloomberg) --</span></section><section class="news-rsf-news-body"><p><a hover="Company Profile" href="javascript:void(0);" itemprop="StoryLink" itemscope="itemscope" link-type="company" target="_blank" ticker="WBA%20US%20EQUITY " title="Company Profile" class="hoverDocumentLink" id="company_WBA%20US%20EQUITY "><meta content="idm403148084" itemprop="ident">
<meta content="true" itemprop="active">
<meta content="bbg://securities/WBA%20US%20Equity" itemprop="url">
<meta content="SecurityLink" itemprop="type">
<meta content="WBA US Equity" itemprop="security">Walgreens Boots Alliance Inc.</a> agreed to acquire Rite Aid Corp. for about $9.4 billion in cash in a transaction to further expand the company's role in the distribution of medications in the U.S.</p>
<p>The Rite Aid transaction, announced Tuesday, would <a hover="See Related Story" href="/document/NWWCLO6K50Y0" itemprop="StoryLink" itemscope="itemscope" link-type="news-stories" news-stories="NWWCLO6K50Y0" target="_blank" title="Walgreens Acquisition of Rite Aid Would Likely Bring FTC Review"><meta content="idm402947380" itemprop="ident">
<meta content="true" itemprop="active">
<meta content="StoryLink" itemprop="type">
<meta content="NWWCLO6K50Y0" itemprop="suid">combine</a> the second- and third-largest drugstore chains in the U.S., with a total of about 12,800 locations, helping Walgreens vault past market leader CVS Health Corp. The acquisition will add to Walgreens' earnings beginning a full year after completion and will produce more than $1 billion in savings from cost overlaps, the companies said Tuesday in a <a hover="See Related Story" href="/document/NWWDP0MEQTXF" itemprop="StoryLink" itemscope="itemscope" link-type="news-stories" news-stories="NWWDP0MEQTXF" target="_blank" title="Walgreens Boots Alliance to Acquire Rite Aid for $17.2 Billion in All-Cash Transaction"><meta content="idm402992828" itemprop="ident">
<meta content="true" itemprop="active">
<meta content="StoryLink" itemprop="type">
<meta content="NWWDP0MEQTXF" itemprop="suid">statement</a>. Including debt, the deal is valued at $17.2 billion, they said.</p>
<p>The company also reported fiscal fourth-quarter earnings showed how it reaps cost savings from mergers. Walgreens said it has saved $799 million in fiscal 2015 after combining with Alliance Boots GmbH last year.</p>
<p><a hover="Company Profile" href="javascript:void(0);" itemprop="StoryLink" itemscope="itemscope" link-type="company" target="_blank" ticker="RAD%20US%20EQUITY " title="Company Profile" class="hoverDocumentLink" id="company_RAD%20US%20EQUITY "><meta content="idm402989828" itemprop="ident">
<meta content="true" itemprop="active">
<meta content="bbg://securities/RAD%20US%20Equity" itemprop="url">
<meta content="SecurityLink" itemprop="type">
<meta content="RAD US Equity" itemprop="security">Rite Aid</a> shares fell 8.2 percent to $7.96 in early trading Wednesday, below Walgreens' offer of $9 a share, reflecting speculation that the transaction will face antitrust scrutiny. They had risen as high as $8.74 earlier after the Wall Street Journal reported the companies were close to a deal. Walgreens shares rose 1.4 percent to $96.50.</p>
<h3>Deal Opportunity</h3>
<p>Rite Aid's stock had slumped 29 percent since Sept. 16, after the company lowered profit and revenue forecasts for the year, giving Walgreens a potential opportunity to make an offer. The price represents a 48 percent premium to Rite Aid's closing price on Monday.</p>
<p>Speculation that Walgreens would pursue Rite Aid rose to a crescendo in March after <span bbg-href="bbg://screens/RICH" itemprop="StoryLink" itemscope="itemscope" title="Bloomberg Billionaires Index">billionaire<meta content="idm402968796" itemprop="ident">
<meta content="bbg://screens/RICH" itemprop="url">
<meta content="RICH" itemprop="function"></span> <span bbg-href="bbg://screens/BBIO%201719695" itemprop="StoryLink" itemscope="itemscope" title="Billionaire Profile">Stefano Pessina<meta content="NWXMJQSYF023" itemprop="ident">
<meta content="bbg://screens/BBIO%201719695" itemprop="url">
<meta content="BBIO 1719695" itemprop="function"></span>, who took over in January as interim chief executive officer at Walgreens after it acquired Alliance Boots, said he envisioned doing his next big deal in the U.S.</p>
<h3>Pharmacy Benefits</h3>
<p>In addition to expanding its drugstore locations, the Rite Aid deal gives Walgreens its first foray into the business of managing drug benefits for insurers and employers, an area where rival CVS is a leader. Rite Aid entered that business by acquiring Envision Pharmaceutical Services Inc. for about $2 billion this year.</p>
<p>If Walgreens aims to get bigger in drug-benefit management, it could use EnvisionRX to acquire other small competitors to build that business, said <a hover="Person Profile" href="javascript:void(0);" itemprop="StoryLink" itemscope="itemscope" link-type="person" person="7366934" title="Person Profile" class="hoverDocumentLink" id="person_7366934"><meta content="idm402962036" itemprop="ident">
<meta content="true" itemprop="active">
<meta content="bbg://people/profile/7366934" itemprop="url">
<meta content="ProfileLink" itemprop="type">
<meta content="7366934" itemprop="profile">Ross Muken</a>, an analyst at Evercore ISI who advises holding the shares.</p>
<p>Rite Aid CEO <a hover="Person Profile" href="javascript:void(0);" itemprop="StoryLink" itemscope="itemscope" link-type="person" person="1983565" title="Person Profile" class="hoverDocumentLink" id="person_1983565"><meta content="idm403145404" itemprop="ident">
<meta content="true" itemprop="active">
<meta content="bbg://people/profile/1983565" itemprop="url">
<meta content="ProfileLink" itemprop="type">
<meta content="1983565" itemprop="profile">John Standley</a> is eligible to receive $23.4 million if he's terminated after the deal, according to data compiled by Bloomberg based on Walgreens' offer price per share.</p>
<p>Shares of drug distributor McKesson Corp. dropped 4.2 percent, while AmerisourceBergen Corp., Walgreens' distribution partner for medications, jumped 4.2 percent. Rite Aid represents about $18 billion of McKesson's revenue, according to Evercore ISI.</p>
<p>On Wednesday, Walgreens <a hover="See Related Story" href="/document/NWXGN36K50XY" itemprop="StoryLink" itemscope="itemscope" link-type="news-stories" news-stories="NWXGN36K50XY" target="_blank" title="Walgreens Posts Profit That Tops Estimates as Sales Increase"><meta content="idm403141484" itemprop="ident">
<meta content="true" itemprop="active">
<meta content="StoryLink" itemprop="type">
<meta content="NWXGN36K50XY" itemprop="suid">reported fiscal fourth-quarter earnings</a> that beat analysts' estimates. Excluding one-time items, earnings were 88 cents a share, beating the 81-cent average of analysts' estimates compiled by Bloomberg. Walgreens' pharmacies filled 222 million prescriptions in the quarter, up 4.6 percent from a year before.</p>
<h3>CVS's Moves</h3>
<p>While Pessina had made clear his appetite for deals, he had been cagey about what kind of acquisition he might pursue. He has said only that the company wanted to participate in what he saw as the inevitable consolidation of the long distribution chain that delivers drugs from manufacturers to patients in the U.S.</p>
<p>While Pessina prowled for a deal, CVS stayed busy. In May, Walgreens' top rival agreed to purchase nursing-home pharmacy Omnicare Inc. for $12.7 billion, expanding services to the country's elderly. Less than four weeks later, CVS struck a deal to acquire Target Corp.'s pharmacies and clinics for $1.9 billion, putting its brand, which includes OneMinute Clinics, in retail locations across 47 states.</p>
<p>"Their biggest competitor in the U.S. has been getting bigger," said <a hover="Person Profile" href="javascript:void(0);" itemprop="StoryLink" itemscope="itemscope" link-type="person" person="16849787" title="Person Profile" class="hoverDocumentLink" id="person_16849787"><meta content="idm403136676" itemprop="ident">
<meta content="true" itemprop="active">
<meta content="bbg://people/profile/16849787" itemprop="url">
<meta content="ProfileLink" itemprop="type">
<meta content="16849787" itemprop="profile">Jonathan Palmer</a>, an analyst at Bloomberg Intelligence.</p>
<p>Walgreens already has a foothold in the drug-distribution business after it signed a 10-year agreement with AmerisourceBergen in 2013 and became the company's third-largest shareholder.</p>
<p>Today's Walgreens was built by acquisition. Pessina developed Bern, Switzerland-based Alliance Boots into a powerhouse through more than three decades of mergers before selling it to Walgreen Co. last year. He's now the company's largest shareholder with a 13 percent stake.</p>
<p>Walgreens will revamp Rite Aid's stores to focus on health, wellness and beauty, just as it has been remaking its own stores since the Alliance Boots deal, the company said. Rite Aid will continue to operate under its own brand at first, though eventually the plan is to integrate the two chains.</p>
<p>The acquirer plans to finance the deal with cash and new debt, it said. UBS AG was Walgreens' financial adviser, with Simpson Thacher &amp; Bartlett LP and Weil, Gotshal &amp; Manges LLP providing legal advice. Citigroup Inc. gave financial advice to Rite Aid, with legal counsel from Skadden, Arps, Slate, Meagher &amp; Flom LLP and Jones Day.</p></section><section class="news-footer"><p>--With assistance from <span itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><link href="http://bloomberg.com/StoryFormat/ContactInfo" itemprop="additionalType">
<meta content="bbg://people/profile/18991472" itemprop="url">
<meta content="amelin3@bloomberg.net" itemprop="email">
<meta content="+1-212-617-3047" itemprop="telephone">
<span itemprop="workLocation" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place"><meta content="New York" itemprop="name"></span><meta content="13216940" itemprop="uuid">
<meta content="18991472" itemprop="pepl">
<meta content="assist" itemprop="role">
<meta content="Anders Melin" itemprop="name">
<a hover="Person Profile" href="javascript:void(0);" itemprop="StoryLink" itemscope="itemscope" link-type="person" person="18991472" title="Person Profile" class="hoverDocumentLink" id="person_18991472"><meta content="NWXIME6K50Y6" itemprop="ident">
<meta content="true" itemprop="active">
<meta content="ProfileLink" itemprop="type">
<meta content="bbg://people/profile/18991472" itemprop="url">
<meta content="18991472" itemprop="profile">Anders Melin</a></span> and <span itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><link href="http://bloomberg.com/StoryFormat/ContactInfo" itemprop="additionalType">
<meta content="bbg://people/profile/19366612" itemprop="url">
<meta content="mmittelman@bloomberg.net" itemprop="email">
<meta content="+1-212-617-1369" itemprop="telephone">
<span itemprop="workLocation" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place"><meta content="New York" itemprop="name"></span><meta content="14874620" itemprop="uuid">
<meta content="19366612" itemprop="pepl">
<meta content="assist" itemprop="role">
<meta content="Melissa Mittelman" itemprop="name">
<a hover="Person Profile" href="javascript:void(0);" itemprop="StoryLink" itemscope="itemscope" link-type="person" person="19366612" title="Person Profile" class="hoverDocumentLink" id="person_19366612"><meta content="NWXIME6K50Y7" itemprop="ident">
<meta content="true" itemprop="active">
<meta content="ProfileLink" itemprop="type">
<meta content="bbg://people/profile/19366612" itemprop="url">
<meta content="19366612" itemprop="profile">Melissa Mittelman</a></span> in New York. <br><br>To contact the reporter on this story:<br><span itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><link href="http://bloomberg.com/StoryFormat/ContactInfo" itemprop="additionalType">
<meta content="bbg://people/profile/2491003" itemprop="url">
<meta content="tharrison5@bloomberg.net" itemprop="email">
<meta content="+1-212-617-6145" itemprop="telephone">
<span itemprop="workLocation" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place"><meta content="New York" itemprop="name"></span><meta content="4538381" itemprop="uuid">
<meta content="2491003" itemprop="pepl">
<meta content="by" itemprop="role">
<meta content="reporter" itemprop="role">
<meta content="Crayton Harrison" itemprop="name">
<a hover="Person Profile" href="javascript:void(0);" itemprop="StoryLink" itemscope="itemscope" link-type="person" person="2491003" title="Person Profile" class="hoverDocumentLink" id="person_2491003"><meta content="NWXIME6K50Y8" itemprop="ident">
<meta content="true" itemprop="active">
<meta content="ProfileLink" itemprop="type">
<meta content="bbg://people/profile/2491003" itemprop="url">
<meta content="2491003" itemprop="profile">Crayton Harrison</a></span> in New York at +1-212-617-6145 or<br><a hover="Web Link" href="mailto:tharrison5@bloomberg.net" target="_blank">tharrison5@bloomberg.net</a><br>To contact the editors responsible for this story:<br><span itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><link href="http://bloomberg.com/StoryFormat/ContactInfo" itemprop="additionalType">
<meta content="bbg://people/profile/2491003" itemprop="url">
<meta content="tharrison5@bloomberg.net" itemprop="email">
<meta content="+1-212-617-6145" itemprop="telephone">
<span itemprop="workLocation" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place"><meta content="New York" itemprop="name"></span><meta content="4538381" itemprop="uuid">
<meta content="2491003" itemprop="pepl">
<meta content="editor" itemprop="role">
<meta content="responsible" itemprop="role">
<meta content="Crayton Harrison" itemprop="name">
<a hover="Person Profile" href="javascript:void(0);" itemprop="StoryLink" itemscope="itemscope" link-type="person" person="2491003" title="Person Profile" class="hoverDocumentLink" id="person_2491003"><meta content="NWXIME6K50Y9" itemprop="ident">
<meta content="true" itemprop="active">
<meta content="ProfileLink" itemprop="type">
<meta content="bbg://people/profile/2491003" itemprop="url">
<meta content="2491003" itemprop="profile">Crayton Harrison</a></span> at +1-212-617-6145 or<br><a hover="Web Link" href="mailto:tharrison5@bloomberg.net" target="_blank">tharrison5@bloomberg.net</a><br><span class="news-rsf-editor-byline"><span itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><link href="http://bloomberg.com/StoryFormat/ContactInfo" itemprop="additionalType">
<meta content="bbg://people/profile/16650820" itemprop="url">
<meta content="darmstrong17@bloomberg.net" itemprop="email">
<meta content="+1-212-617-8933" itemprop="telephone">
<span itemprop="workLocation" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place"><meta content="New York" itemprop="name"></span><meta content="6891420" itemprop="uuid">
<meta content="16650820" itemprop="pepl">
<meta content="editor" itemprop="role">
<meta content="primary" itemprop="role">
<meta content="Drew Armstrong" itemprop="name">Drew Armstrong</span></span></p></section>
</newsstory><div class="rsf-scripts"><script type="text/javascript">function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {}</script></div>



</div>
```

How can I strip out only the section that starts with `<section class="news-rsf-abstract"></section>` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

```
<section class="x123"></section>
<section class="x456"></section>
<section class="y789"></section>
```

To remove a section element by class that starts with "x":

```
$('section[class^="x"]').remove();
```

Comment: @ReazurRahman: hey, **YES** it does: http://jsfiddle.net/sstbfh3k/. You haven't included jQuery library into the Fiddle!!

Comment: He isn't including the jquery libraries in his fiddle.

Comment: You guys are right i forgot to include Jquery. It's working like a charm now.  Thanks

Comment: @ReazurRahman: Excellent! Be sure to accept the answer that helped you most. Good luck.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid What does ^ means and why are we using that.

Comment: @ReazurRahman: it tells jQuery to select elements that start with a given string. It's called an 'Attribute Starts With Selector' and can you can learn more about them here: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: Thanks a lot @PaparazzoKid

Answer (score -1):

if it's the only one with that class name, this will work:

```
$("section[class='news-rsf-abstract']").remove();
```

If not, but it's always the first section tag, this will work:

```
$('#chunk_content').find('section').first().remove();
```

If neither of those are true, you will need additional criteria to make sure you target the right section element.

Comment: @ReazurRahman the code in your fiddle is different than the code that I posted.  That aside, you need to include the jquery libraries or "$" will be undefined (check the console for errors).

Comment: @ReazurRahman glad to hear it!  Make sure you accept the answer that helped you the most.  Also, you should upvote any answer that helped you.  These measures will help future users with a similar problem more quickly find the best possible answer.